# Elasticsearch: characters in routing?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have keys that I want to setup routing for in elasticsearch. I have some keys that have special characters (eg: &, ") - how can I setup routing for such keys. Examples:

`"A&B"`

Comment: When I search (using routing in the uri), I get and error with:

reason: 'request [/myindex/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [B"]' }

It is being called as follows: /partb-2017-06-*/_search?routing="A&B"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to [URL-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the routing parameter value since `&` is a reserved character in URLs that introduces a new parameter. In your case, the `routing` parameter has the value `"A` and then another parameter called `B"` is introduced, which ES doesn't know about, hence why it complains.

```
/partb-2017-06-*/_search?routing="A&B"
                                   ^
                                   |
                    this introduces a new parameter
```

The right way to do it is to URL-encode `"A&B"` into `%22A%26B%22` and ES will not complain anymore.

```
/partb-2017-06-*/_search?routing=%22A%26B%22
```